# In NESTJS how do you share the same instance of a Guard between multiple modules?

Tags: nestjs

module Auth exports Guard AuthGuard

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

@Module({
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  exports: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

This is AuthGuard

```js
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(){
    console.log('instantiated');
  }

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    return true;
  }
}
```

CatsModule's controller CatsController depends on AuthGuard

```js
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth.guard';

@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(): string[]{
    return ['Oliver'];
  }
}
```

so CatsModule is configured to import AuthModule (which exports AuthGuard)

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatsController } from './cats.controller';
import { AuthModule } from 'src/auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule],
  controllers: [CatsController]
})
export class CatsModule {}
```

When the application bootstrap I can see `AuthGuard` being instantiated twice, once by the `AuthModule` and once by the `CatsController`.

my question is: how can I make sure `CatsController` uses the `AuthGuard` instance instantiated by the `AuthModule`, instead of instantiating its own one?

Regards,

Davide

Comment: It's possible this is just a current limitation of nest js but I'm curious if this affects the way the guard is working for you?

Comment: I am having the same thoughts as I don't know when and how does Guards get instanticated. My guards works even if  i don't put it in Prodivers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rule into your **AuthGuard** Class to instance only once. Then your Class will be a **Singleton**.

For that you need to add a Class property

```
static instance: AuthGuard;
```

And inside the constructor of AuthGuard Class you need to add this:

```
constructor() {
  if (!AuthGuard.instance) {
    [..your init Class code goes here...]
    AuthGuard.instance = this;
  }
  return AuthGuard.instance;
}
```

Then you will have only one instance of the Class!